# The localization of smooth boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ with smooth boundary and $p \in \partial\Omega$ a fixed point. For any $0<r<R$, can we find an open set $\Omega_1$ with smooth boundary such that

1.$\Omega_1 \subseteq B_p(R) \cap \Omega$,

2.$\partial \Omega  \cap {B_p}(r) \subseteq \partial {\Omega _1}$     (where $B_p(R)$ is a ball with center $p$ and radius $R$)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In some neighborhood of $p$, the domain $\Omega$ is described by inequality $f<0$, with $f$ smooth and vanishing on $\partial \Omega$, and such that $\nabla f\ne 0$ on $\partial \Omega$.  (One calls $f$ a *defining function* for $\Omega$.)

Let $\varphi:\mathbb R\to [0,\infty)$ be a $C^\infty$ function such that $\varphi(t)=0$ when $t\le 0$ and $\varphi(t)>0$ when $t>0$.

Let $g(x) = f(x)+M\varphi( |x-p| - r)$ where $M$ is large. Note that $g$ is as smooth as $f$. In the ball $B_p(r)$ we have $g\equiv f$, but after that $g$ rapidly grows. If $M$ is large enough, the set $\Omega_1 = \{x:g(x)<0\}$ does what you want.

Well, not quite: we have to worry about $\nabla g$ vanishing somewhere in $B_p(R)\setminus B_p(r)$. But this can be avoided with Sard's lemma, since $M$ can vary.

Comment: How can you show $\Omega_1 \subseteq B_p(R) \cap \Omega$?

Comment: @Hezudao Make $M$ large enough so that $M\varphi(R-r)>-\min_{|x-p|=R}f$. This ensures that the set $\{g<0\}$ does not meet the sphere $\{x:|x-p|=R\}$. What happens outside the sphere is not important; take $\Omega_1$ to be the appropriate connected component of $\{g<0\}$.